# edit data grid in window mobile c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, window, windows-mobile

In window mobile c#,the data grid is read only in default mode. I want to edit data by programmatically. So, how can i change the data grid in editable mode? Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

U can create dynamic grid and set colum read only property as false .For more details go through this link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/323268/How-to-make-a-column-in-datagridview-editable